# (<class 'sqlite3.OperationalError'>, OperationalError('unrecognized token: ":"',))

Tags: python, sqlite, web

I use python to process web page.
I download the souce code of the page. And I want to store the code in sqlite.
And it raise the Exception.

`sql = """insert into warrent(link, content) values ('%s', '%s')""" % (url, page)
self.curs.execute(sql)`

Answer (score -1, accepted):

try the following:

```
sql = "INSERT INTO warrent(link, content) values (\'{0}\', \'{1}\')".format(url,page)
self.curs.execute(sql)
```

In your example \' won't the ":" from url.

Cheers,
Jakub

Comment: Point taken. How else would you recommend to do that:
self.curs.execute("INSERT INTO warrent(link, content) values (?, ?)", (url, page))
?

Comment: AttributeError: 'str' object has no attribute 'format'
I use python 2.5.2

Comment: what if there are single quotes in the sql.
repalce with two single quotes?

Comment: but is there any better solution?

Answer (score 0):

I also ran into the same problem. The solution is quite simple.
Do this before making "sql" string:

```
url = '"'+url+'"'
```

The problems arises because inside the string the " symbol is not present sql sees it as a command rather than as a string.